# Entity with Updates Mapped to Stored Procedure Not Tracking

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have some views mapped in Entity Framework. Those entities have Insert/Update/Delete Stored Procedures mapped for modifications.

The proxy entities seem not to be detecting changes properly. That is, if I check the ObjectStateManager for the ObjectStateEntry for my Person entity, and the State is Unchanged...if I update the FirstName property, the State remains Unchanged (it should be modified). These instances are indeed self tracking proxies...and more interestingly, if I change the value of a property on that entity that is mapped to an Association, the entity state does change to Modified...

Other entities in the edmx model that are directly mapped to tables do not seem afflicted by this problem (any changes are correctly reflected in the ObjectStateEntry).

What's going wrong here?